# exclude test sources from boot-clj project for production

Tags: testing, clojure, boot-clj

I'm developing a ClojureScript library, which is intended to be used in a browser environment.

So obviously there will be additional source files during development and testing. How can this be separated from the library source?

Is there a way to mark some sources as just for testing purpose which would be omitted when installing / deploying the project?

Additionally the resources folder, which contains some HTML files (etc.), should not be included when publishing as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.boot` put only those files that you want in your final build to `:source-paths`.

Add your test files only when defining a test-setup task like this:

```clj
(deftask test-setup []
  (merge-env! :source-path #{"dir_with_tests"})
  indentity)
```

And use it in your boot test task:

```clj
(deftask test []
  (comp
    (test-setup)
    (your-test-task)))
```